# AirPods Pro show as connected on iPhone, but don't appear as Speaker

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, airpods

On my iPhone 11, my AirPods Pro show as connected in the Bluetooth settings, but are not available as an option as an external speaker.

One of or a combination of the following will eventually work, but never consistently:

- Resetting my AirPods: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209463
- Forgetting and reconnecting my AirPods.
- Threatening to reboot my iPhone (ie. Press lock and volume, and reaching the screen where you can swipe to reboot)
- Actually rebooting my iPhone

Both my iPhone's OS and the AirPods firmware are up to date.

Does anyone know what the root cause might be, or a consistent way to resolve it?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I would try contacting Apple support.

Comment: Yeah I've tried contacting Apple. They recommended resetting the AirPods and also cleaning them. Neither did the trick unfortunately. Next step is to have them looked at, which I'm keen to avoid if possible. Thanks.